# Find the limit of the bounded decreasing sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the limit of the bounded decreasing sequence defined by
>
> $a_1=3 \\a_{n+1}= \frac{1}{4-a_n}+1$

Can anyone teach me how to do this question? Thanks.

The answer is $\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$.

Comment: Well, if you know it is bounded and decreasing then you know the limit, $L$, exists...in which case we must have $L=\frac 1{4-L}+1$.  But how do you know it is bounded and decreasing?

Comment: Take limits on both sides of the recurrence.

Comment: Do you have to prove it is bounded and decreasing?

Comment: You can actually get the closed form expression for $a_n$.

Comment: The question say that it is bounded and decreasing

Comment: @YuxiaoXie Oh, really?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt All recurrence relations of the form $a_{n+1}=k(a_n-x)/(a_n-y)$ can be solved. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence relation is $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n-5}{a_n-4},$$ and for this kind of recurrence we have a trick to calculate the general formula.

The equation $$\frac{x-5}{x-4}=x$$ is called the *characteristic equation* of the recurrence relation and let us denote its roots (called *characteristic roots*) by $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then after some (ugly) calculations we can get $$\frac{a_{n+1}-\alpha}{a_{n+1}-\beta}=k\frac{a_n-\alpha}{a_n-\beta},$$ where $k$ is some constant. Now this is a geometric progression and can be easily solved.

Comment: Huh, interesting, though I don't see how to get a closed form for $a_n$ from that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Why? $\{(a_n-\alpha)/(a_n-\beta)\}$ is a geometric progression! We know its inital term, we know $k$ (which can be computed directly), and we know $(a_n-\alpha)/(a_n-\beta)=f(n)$, where $f$ only depends on $n$, and we only have to solve for $a_n$.

Comment: Oh duh, silly me xD Sorry, just woke up, but my brain isn't quite there yet.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's okay. Actually it's strange that many people are unaware of this trick...

Comment: Yup, that checks out.  Wonderful!  Another tool to put in my toolbox :-) Thanks!

Comment: There are two solution for your equation: $x=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2},\:x=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: But why $\:x=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ should be ignored? Thanks.

Comment: @kdhug886 Yes, they're denoted by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (becasue I'm too lazy to do the calculations...). Now you just substitute $a_{n+1}=(a_n-5)/(a_n-4)$ in $(a_{n+1}-\alpha)/(a_{n+1}-\beta)$ and see what you get.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Another method on how to get a closed form (for a slightly more general problem): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016281/prove-convergence-of-hyperbolic-recursive-series/2374325#2374325

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}$.

Write $\lim a_n = k$ and you have  by simple limit arithmetic properties that $k  = \dfrac{1}{4-k} + 1$.

From here you can find $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove that $a_n\leq3$.

Indeed, $a_1\leq3$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-a_n}+1\leq\frac{1}{4-3}+1=2<3$.

In another hand $a_1>\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$ and
$$a_{n+1}-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{1}{4-a_n}-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}=\frac{1}{4-a_n}-\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}=$$
$$= \frac{1}{4-a_n}-\frac{1}{4-\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}}=\frac{a_n-\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}}{(4-a_n)\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt5}{2}\right)},$$
which gives $a_n>\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ by induction and
$$a_n-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}<\left(\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}\right)^1\left(a_{n-1}-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)<$$
$$<\left(\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}\right)^2\left(a_{n-2}-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)<...<\left(\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}\right)^{n-1}\left(a_1-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$
and since $\frac{2}{3+\sqrt5}<1$ we obtain
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$$
by the limit definition.